# Prove a inequality about function and its derivate

Tags: calculus

We know that $f$ is a differentiable function, where $$ f :\mathbb{R} \to (0,\infty) $$
Its derivative satisfies $$ |f'(x)-f'(y)|\leq |x-y| $$
Now I need to prove $$ (f'(x)^2)<2f(x)$$

---

I have try to let $x,y$ are $f(x)$ and $-f(x)$ ,and want to use the inequality given in the problem,but it’s hard to do it.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Can you show your attempts for to solve this problem?

Comment: @АлександрПальма I want to construct a function whose derivate is $$ f'(x)^2-f(x)$$, and show that it is decreasing,I also

Comment: @АлександрПальма I also try to let x,y are $$f(x)$$,and $$-f(x)$$,then use the lipschtiz condition of the $$f'(x)$$,but both my try are failed

Comment: Write down what you have tried in the question in case it gets closed.